# Why Segmentation Faults occur?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I just started to learn C and need some helps. I already compiled my code and fixed all warnings that occur. However, when I run my program it says 'Segmentation Fault' and this is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char *sorting(char word[51], int n) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            if (word[i] > word[j]) {
                char temp = word[i];
                word[i] = word[j];
                word[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

From above, I just sort the word in order to use in `strcmp`.

First I will read file that contains jumbled words. Next read dictionary's file. Then I will check whether two words are the same.

```
int main(int argc, char **dict, char **jambles)
{
    const char *j = jambles[1];
    FILE *jambles_file = fopen(j, "r");
    char jambles_words[51];

    while (fgets(jambles_words, sizeof(jambles_words), jambles_file)) {

        int count = 0;
        const char *d = dict[1];
        FILE *dict_file = fopen(d ,"r");
        char dict_words[51];

        printf("%s", jambles_words);

        while (fgets(dict_words, sizeof(dict_words), dict_file)) {

            int length_jambles = strlen(jambles_words);
            int length_dict = strlen(dict_words);
            char *j_ = jambles_words;
            char *d_ = dict_words;
            const char *sort_jambles = sorting(j_, length_jambles);
            const char *sort_dict = sorting(d_, length_dict);

            if (length_jambles == length_dict) {
                int compare = strcmp(sort_jambles, sort_dict);
                if (compare == 0) {
                    printf("%s", dict_words);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else if (count == 0) {
                printf("NO MACTHES");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I still don't know what are the mistakes of my code even I already search on the internet for the causes of Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Short answer: You messed something up and accessed memory you don't have access to. One way to do this is to blow past the limits of your buffer. Tip: `%50s` and **always** check important return values.

Comment: `int main(int argc, char **dict, char **jambles)` ????

Comment: That's an invalid [`main` function declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function). Depending on system it might work, but not as you expect.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I searched on the internet about how to create arguments for `int main()`

Comment: @linggS. That is a valid way to define a main function on POSIX systems. I'm just worried that based on the names you chose for the arguments, that you don't know what they actually contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the root cause is that you misunderstand how command-line arguments are passed to C programs. When you run `./a.out foo bar` and it calls into `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)`, `"foo"` will be in `argv[1]` and `"bar"` will be in `argv[2]`. `envp` will just contain environment variables like `"TERM=xterm"` and `"PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"`. You appear to think that `"bar"` will instead end up in `envp[1]`, which is incorrect.

The more immediate cause is likely that because of the above, your call to `fopen` is failing due to a file called `"TERM=xterm"` or something not existing, and so returning `NULL`, which you then pass to `fgets` blindly. In general, it's Undefined Behavior to pass null pointers to any standard library function that doesn't specifically say what doing so will do.

Comment: oh now i understand more about `int main()` tysm, could you please explain more about `fopen` and `fgets` that you mentioned.

Comment: @linggS. I just added some more explanation.

Comment: You can check if the file is, in fact, open by being not a null-pointer. See [fopen](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fopen.html).